# Download text from html pre tag

Tags: javascript, html, pre

I want to download all text that my pre tag contains.

I tried this code:

```js
 function saveTextAsFile() {
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById('textArea').value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = "proxies.txt";
        
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null) {
       // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
       // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    } else {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }
    downloadLink.click();
}
var button = document.getElementById('save');
button.addEventListener('click', saveTextAsFile);
```

```html
<pre id="textarea">
  1
  2
  3
</pre>
<button type="button" value="save" id="save"> Save</button>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vb7z1jeu/41/)

But it seems to work only for textarea, not pre tag.

Anyone has an idea how to accomplish this? :)

Comment: you can copy content from `pre` to `input(type='hidden')` and get from it

Comment: `pre` does not have `value`, check `console.log(textToWrite);`

Comment: Well i really don't know anything in JS (as you may already see), so can you give little bit more explanation, please? :)

Comment: be attention <pre id="textarea"> but in js getElementById('textArea'). Need getElementById('textarea')

Answer (score 2):

Change textToWrite assignment to this:

`var textToWrite = document.getElementById('textarea').innerText;`

Then remove the reference to "destroyClickedElement" on the "onclick" event, as that function doesn't exist in your code, and instead use an anonymous function:

```
downloadLink.onclick = function(){
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
};
```

You can see it working in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fwe2wkqq/2/

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, check my updated answer, to see how to properly remove the generated link once it's clicked.

Comment: Yeah, sure.­­­­

Comment: Hey, this code actually doesn't work...It just downloads text file, but text inside is just "undefined".

Comment: You're correct. Answer and fiddle updated to reflect that.

Comment: Good! :)­­­­­­­

Comment: Btw it just downloads text without line breaks? You have any idea how to fix this? :|

Comment: Actually, it is downloading WITH line breaks, if you test my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/fwe2wkqq/2/) and open the text file in your text editor, you'll see it has line breaks.

Comment: Windows (Notepad) uses the `\r\n` character sequence to indicate a line break. I'm a using a Mac, where in the same fashion as Linux, uses a simple `\n` for a line break. If you open the file with another Windows-based editor that respects the `\n` line break, like Notepad++ or Sublime Text, you'll see the line breaks correctly.

Comment: Nice to know that but i still haven't got what i need :p

Comment: **ANSWER:** Adding `textToWrite = textToWrite.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n");` below variable textToWrite fixes the problem.